# Get time interval in mysql

Tags: mysql, time, intervals

is there a query for me to get the time interval - One minute, five minutes, quarter hour, half hour, hour, and day? I use MySQL as a database.

Comment: what do you mean "get the time interval".  what do the tables look like

Comment: they probably mean... "2 days ago" or something

Comment: yea like that, like an hour ago, what are the values an hour ago. like that. on the table i have the id, timestamp, and then the value

Answer (score 12, accepted):

to get a range, like from 30 to 45 minutes ago, do like this

```
SELECT * FROM tbl 
WHERE tbl.mydate > DATE(DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 45 MINUTE)) 
AND tbl.mydate < DATE(DATE_sub(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE));
```

Comment: You need to remove DATE() from the Where clause otherwise it doesn't do minute ranges it just does the days.
I know this is from years ago, but I was trying to find why this wasn't working for me, and may benefit others using this answer in their own code

Answer (score 8):

You are probably looking for [date_sub](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add):

```
SELECT * FROM YOURTABLE t
WHERE t.timestamp > date_sub(NOW(), interval 1 hour);
```

For different intervals you can change the 1 hour to 5 days, 5 weeks, etc).

From the documentation:

> **DATE_SUB(date,INTERVAL expr unit)**
>
> The date argument specifies the starting date or datetime value. expr
>   is an expression specifying the interval value to be added or
>   subtracted from the starting date. expr is a string; it may start with
>   a “-” for negative intervals. unit is a keyword indicating the units
>   in which the expression should be interpreted.
>
> The following table shows the expected form of the expr argument for
>   each unit value.

```
unit Value     Expected expr Format

MICROSECOND    MICROSECONDS
SECOND         SECONDS
MINUTE         MINUTES
HOUR           HOURS
DAY            DAYS
WEEK           WEEKS
MONTH          MONTHS
QUARTER        QUARTERS
YEAR           YEARS
```